# UIColor Swift gives a different Color

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to use this Color

`share.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 53, green: 155, blue: 220, alpha: 0.5)`

Which it supposed to be a light blue " Not an expert of Colors "
but it gives me a pink color..

i've tried to divide by 255 as follow
`share.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 53/255, green: 155/255, blue: 220/255, alpha: 0.5)`

[image]

But didn't work for me, am i missing something or doing something wrong ?

Comment: It works for me. I get a light blue colour with your second snippet.

Comment: Uhmm... Weird but it didn't work out for me.

Comment: try adding .0 to your numbers 53.0/255.0

Comment: You should use CGFloat value, make it like 53.0, 155.0, 220.0,  share.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 53.0/255, green: 155.0/255, blue: 220.0/255, alpha: 0.5)

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/585261/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-19%20at%2019.37.53.png Works without forcing the divisor to a float.

Comment: Your code is still passing parameters greater than 1.0. Try using the method you've shown in your second snippet.

Comment: You're using integer division like 5/2 == 2 and not 2.5. So one number has to be a double/float for each devision.

Comment: Same issue i tried to add 0s, still gives me the same Color

Comment: Look at the screenshot. I didn't use a float, but it works.

Comment: @DevAndArtist It actually works

Comment: Your parameters are incorrect. So you are getting a White colour with an opacity of 0.5, above a red button, which is why it is giving you pink.

Comment: @Abizem i tried the values according to the image, also it didn't work out... it gives me the same color, is it my xCode version like Corrupted ?

Comment: Probably not. But it would be nice if you actually pasted the code you are using and saying doesn't work. Because - as you can see for yourself in a playground - it clearly does.

Comment: @Abizem i edited my question.. and i uploaded an image of the pink color and Look at the left of the simulator you will see the my code

Comment: The variables are mixed up.. i know.. but No i'm not Assigning any the colors to other buttons, ill edit the post again to add the actual code...

Comment: it worked it was because of the Alpha value which it should be 1.0.. uhmm How i didn't think of that... Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code is incorrect, that is translated to 1.0, 1.0, 1.0:

`let color = UIColor(red: 53, green: 155, blue: 220, alpha: 0.5)`

[image]

You need to divide it by 255.0 to get it in range 0-1.0, then you should get the right result:

`let color = UIColor(red: 53.0/255.0, green: 155.0/255.0, blue: 220.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)`

[image]

The only way to get pink with this is combining it with another color. The thing is, that your background color is prone to mixing with another color - you are setting opacity to 0.5. Therefore combining with something else which may be behind it is a very much compelling reason to this behavior. Set the alpha to 1.0 and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Michal.. it really worked :).. but still there is something Confuses me.. you know the answer that @DevAndArtist provide self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 53/255.0, green: 155/255.0, blue: 220/255.0, alpha: 0.5), it worked for him... why it didn't work for me ?

Comment: He did it in a "test view controller", not in the same environment as you (table view cell action). If you look in the documentation for the `backgroundColor` property on `UITableViewRowAction`, it says - *If you do not specify a value for this property, UIKit assigns a default color based on the value in the style property.*. My bets are that the row action didn't like the alpha component you set to 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this on some test view controller and I've got the light blue color as expected (Xcode 7 beta 3):

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 53/255.0, green: 155/255.0, blue: 220/255.0, alpha: 0.5)
```

[image]